# Passing request parameters through Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, httprequest

I have  a struts application, and I am trying to call the Action class with an URL. When I try to pass the request parameters, none of them get appended.

Here is the code I have :

```
    document.myform.action = "mydetails_${firmID}_${empID}.action?id=56";
    document.myform.submit();
```

But this is what I see in chrome console :

> mydetails_123_04.action?

For some resaon, the stuff after the question mark is not appended. Am I missing something ?

Comment: How about `"mydetails_${firmID}_${empID}.action" + "?id=56"` ?

Comment: I don't know what's up with your string, but given that you're submitting a form what's wrong with `<input type="hidden" id="56">` in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you can set params like that in the action. You need to add them as parameters in the form, which involves creating a hidden input node:

```
var input = document.createElement( 'input' ); 
input.type = 'hidden';
input.name = 'id';
input.value = 56;
document.forms.myform.appendChild( input );​
```